# How to embed plplot graphs into ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

Anyone know if this is possible?, What I want is to design a ncurses interface with graphing functions are entered using a mathematical expression parser (matheval), but before continuing I want to know if this is technically possible. (I have integrated already in my program matheval and working)

Answer (score 0):

ncurses is character based, you can't embed graphics.

There are limited graphics functions to draw boxes and horizontal and vertical lines, but these use special characters.